# Can't apply terraform through OctopusDeploy with AzureRM backend through proxy

Tags: terraform, octopus-deploy, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use the OctopusDeploy terraform apply step to generate my infrastructure using an AzureRM backend. The backend is set up and works from my computer.

When I try it from OctoopusDeploy it doesn't seem to be able to get through the Proxy - which is an authenticating proxy.

I've got the proxy set up in OctopusDeploy (and the packages are fed from a NuGet feed which comes through the proxy) and I have HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY set in the system environment variables. The Octopus service is running as a user that has permissions to use the internet through the proxy

Here's the output:

```
Info    Extracting package: C:\Octopus\OctopusServer\PackageCache\feeds-app-hub\TF_AppHub@S1.1.35248@7308A1964B1A0D48AF04BB90C9FBB55D.nupkg 
Info    terraform.exe init -no-color -input=false -get-plugins=true -backend-config= access_key=<acc_key>
Info    Initializing the backend... 
Info    Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically use this backend unless the backend configuration changes. 
Error    Error refreshing state: Get https://<storage_acc>.blob.core.windows.net/modules/dev2.terraform.tfstate: proxyconnect tcp: EOF 
Fatal    The remote script failed with exit code 1 
Fatal    The action Create Infrastructure on the Octopus Server failed
```

Comment: This was [resolved](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/4913) in version 2018.8.7.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll install it and give it a try.